# Does solr makes use of multi processor machine?

Tags: multithreading, solr, cpu-architecture

Is Dual Core machine really required for running a SOLR instance. There are 50 Services accessing the instance Currently. Would Dual Core Machine be of any good?

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment so I'll try an answer instead. This is a complex question. The short answer is that, yes, Solr can make use of multiple CPUs in a variety of ways. As to weather it 'would be worth it', you need to provide more information. A dual core is not required, but may improve performance. Also look at Solr Cloud.

Comment: Any references to how to achieve that?

Comment: Only what Google turns up.